# String to bitmap converters windows phone

Tags: c#, exception, memory, bitmap, converters

Hey Guys my program gets an image from an `IsolatedStorage` file and then displays it on my dashboard. it works fine until it gets to the fourth picture on the dashboard and then it throws an `OutOfMemoryException`. Below is the code :

```
public class StringToBitmapConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] data;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isf.FileExists(value.ToString()))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile(value.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    // Allocate an array large enough for the entire file 
                    data = new byte[isfs.Length];
                    // Read the entire file and then close it 
                    isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    isfs.Close();
                }


                // Create memory stream and bitmap 
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

                // Set bitmap source to memory stream 

                bi.SetSource(ms);

                ms.Dispose();

                return bi;


            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

please can you tell me what is wrong with the code so i can fix he problem?

This is the error i get when the app crashes:

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `BeginInit` and `EndInit`:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.StreamSource = ms;
    bi.EndInit();
}
```

Comment: do i need a namespace or declare the method anywhere because it is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: Oops, I think it's `StreamSource` instead of `SetSource` (updated).

Comment: when i use it, this is the error i get:                                         Error 1 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInit' and no extension method 'BeginInit' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.begininit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, i just dnt gt why it isnt working. but tanx though.i wld look more into it maybe im doing something wrong.